# Set Billing Address to be Not Required in Contribution Page

Tags: contribution-page

Authorize.net does not require a billing address. How can I configure my CiviCRM to also not require that on a Contribution page?

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised that Authorize.net does not require a billing address!  I don't recall ever seeing that.

With that said, I would recommend you still require billing addresses.  Right now the volume of fraudulent credit card transactions on non-profit sites seems to be skyrocketing and anything you can do to protect yourself would be prudent. The last thing you want is to have Authorize turn off your account due to fraud and you won't get any contributions then!

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue correlate, ie do you have some fields that are required and are in the Billing Block and not otherwise available to the user via a profile? [15118](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15118)

Only suggesting it as it just came up [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/5145/civievent-registration-with-pay-later-prevented-with-missing-fields-error/5149)

Comment: or possibly related to https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17082 ?

Comment: No, none of these are related. My boss just wants the billing address to be NOT required to make it easier to donate, that's all.