# CiviEvent registration with pay later prevented with "missing fields" error

Tags: civievent

We're running 4.6.8 on WordPress 4.2.4. I'm not finding guidance on this searching the web. Here's the CiviEvent registration page link:

http://civicrm.jrpc.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/register&page_id=111

We have an event that when registering by PayPal - it all works. But if "pay later" is chosen - it's complaining about missing fields that have already been filled out (address), or for the first and last name- it complains about the Country and Billing Name & Address that are not in our requested profile. Full error below:

Please correct the following errors in the form fields below:

```
Billing First Name is a required field.
Billing Last Name is a required field.
Street Address is a required field.
City is a required field.
State/Province is a required field.
Postal Code is a required field.
Country is a required field.
```

Any ideas? Our last event (before a few civievent upgrades), this feature worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at [this issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17082).

Answer (score 1):

There have been discussions in past about what happens if a required filled is in the Billing address block but is not ALSO included in a Profile. Not sure how closely that matches your scenario but try JIRA [15118](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15118)

Otherwise googling for "pay later" and 'billing' and 'required' might score you something. hth

Answer (score 1):

You just needs to unchecked the **billing address required** option under event configuration fees tab.

Sitename/civicrm/event/manage/fees/?reset=1&action=update&id=...