# Event Registration (Pay Later) does not retain address

Tags: civievent, paylater

Since upgrading civi back in fall of last year to 4.6.4 (Wordpress 4.4.2) event registrations no longer retain the address for a new user. (I have a profile set up with all the fields pertinent to mailing address set up.)

The confirmation page shows all the information in the profile, but the confirmation email is missing all the address fields and there are not retained in the contact that is created.

I've read [this post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/5145/civievent-registration-with-pay-later-prevented-with-missing-fields-error) about errors when you have "Billing address required" checked. That's not the case here, I don't have that checked. I'm guessing it is still somewhat related? But why would civi eat the mailing address if no billing address is provided???

Comment: Hi Ray,  did you check the civicrm log for any errors that occurred around this time? If there are any please could you paste them?

Comment: @JohnFF unfortunately nothing pops up in the error log.

Comment: Sounds like something deeper is going on. I'd ask a developer to (preferably with a debugger) step throuh the process and find out why this data isn't being stored.