# Billing Address - Can i turn off saving billing addresses?

Tags: civicontribute, addresses

When someone pays by credit card it stores their billing address to the contact record. We are using auth.net for credit card payments. Is there a way to turn this off? I do not want to store billing addresses on each contact record.

Comment: Have you checked https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/5115/set-billing-address-to-be-not-required-in-contribution-page?

Comment: I think those all relate to not requiring the billing address. what i am looking for is it just not saving the billing address to the contact record. i still want it to ask for the billing address when a payment is made.